# Is it possible to pass data between two JQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, draggable, z-index

I have two **jquery plugin** of my own and the elements created by the two plugin had its own **z-index value**.E.g:

```
// auto increase the z-index value 
// auto increase the z-index to the maximum of their own when I drag it.

element1 created by plugin1 and has the z-index:1;
element2 created by plugin1 and has the z-index:2;
....

// auto increase the z-index value 
// auto increase the z-index to the maximum of their own when I drag it.

element2 created by plugin2 and has the z-index:1;
element2 created by plugin2 and has the z-index:2;
.....
```

and both of them can be **draggable**,so when I click one of them I want its **z-index value** to be the **maximum of all the elements I created**.But now the **z-index** were separated!

I am using **JQuery UI draggable plugin** but don't like the **stack option** !

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using name spaces

for eg in plugin 1
you can define

```
var Plugin1 = {}; //data abuot the plugin
Plugin1.element1 = {}; //data about the element
Plugin1.element1.zindex = 1000; //data about the element
```

This can be retrieved in any part of the js
but make sure its defined before document.ready